# Why is setTimeout game loop experiencing lag when touchstart event fires?

Tags: javascript, android, google-chrome, debugging, game-loop

This is a rather specific problem I'm having. The glitch only seems to appear in the latest update of Chrome for Android, so here are the specs:

Application Version:
Chrome 45.0.2454.84

Operating System:
Android 4.4.4; XT1031 Build/KXB21.14-L2.4

I'm using a Moto G, but the glitch also occurred on a Samsung running the same version of Chrome. Anyway, the problem is clearly that `touchstart` events interrupt my `window.setTimeout` game loop. Here's the code:

```
(
    function rafTouchGlitch() {
        /////////////////
        /* FUNCTIONS. */
        ///////////////

        function touchStartWindow(event_) {
            event_.preventDefault();
        }

        ///////////////////////
        /* OBJECT LITERALS. */
        /////////////////////

        var engine = {
            /* FUNCTIONS. */
            start : function(interval_) {
                var handle = this;

                (function update() {
                    handle.timeout = window.setTimeout(update, interval_);

                    /* Draw the background and the red square. */
                    display.fillStyle = "#303030";
                    display.fillRect(0, 0, display.canvas.width, display.canvas.height);

                    display.fillStyle = "#f00000";
                    display.fillRect(red_square.x, red_square.y, 20, 20);

                    /* Update the square's position. */
                    red_square.x++;

                    if (red_square.x > display.canvas.width) {
                        red_square.x = -20;
                    }
                })();
            },
            /* VARIABLES. */
            timeout : undefined
        };

        red_square = {
            /* VARIABLES. */
            x : 0,
            y : 0
        };

        /////////////////
        /* VARIABLES. */
        ///////////////

        var display = document.getElementById("canvas").getContext("2d");

        //////////////////
        /* INITIALIZE. */
        ////////////////

        window.addEventListener("touchstart", touchStartWindow);

        engine.start(1000 / 60);
    })();
```

This code works fine in any other browser and even in previous versions of Chrome. It worked fine in the last release, but for some reason now there's a problem. I'm not sure if this is a bug on Chrome's end or if they're doing something new and I'm the one not covering my bases, but the fact remains that there's a glaring lag in my game loop when `touchstart` events fire.

Here's a fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/dhjsqqxn/

Tap the screen and see how the red square lags! It's ridiculous. You can basically freeze the Timeout object by tapping the screen fast enough.

If you have an Android phone, I urge you to update Chrome and visit the link to see what I mean. If this is a bug it's a huge one, considering how valuable `setTimeout` is and how vital `touchstart` is on mobile. If it's not a bug, I'd really like to know what I'm doing wrong.

Thanks for your time!

Answer (score 6):

See https://bugs.chromium.org/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=567800

Android Chrome does not run scheduled(setTimeout/setInterval) callbacks during touchmove.

As a workaround you can try window.requestAnimationFrame() or run the callback manually in touchmove event which would require to keep/check a last-run time.

Comment: Thanks so much for this, your answer deserves more upvotes. Googling for "touchstart lag" returns a bunch of results about a different issue, that's solved by FastClick, or some sort of meta tag user-scalable fixes with older Chrome/Safari. This question is the only one that's related to THIS specific issue. The true fix is to use requestAnimationFrame() as you said, instead of setTimeout().

Comment: still its annoying that for example on jquery-3.3.1.js line 3640 the call window.setTimeout( process ); does get postponned resulting in apparent "slow app" when you use the deferred methods /promises...

Comment: For me, it only didn't execute setInterval when I was using `preventDefault` on a touchmove event.. and only if that touchmove event was set after touchstart already went off

Answer (score 2):

Do "return false;" at the end of the touchstart func.

for a swipe the following jquery without jquerymobile..

```
$("#id").on({'touchstart' : functionforstart, 'touchmove' :onmove, 'touchend' : functionforend});

functionforstart(e){ e.originalEvent.touches[0].pageX usw.. return false;}

function onmove(e){lastMove=e}

function functionforend(){lastMove.originalEvent.touches[0].pageX} usw..    e.prefentDefault(); }
```

That works for me.. var lastMove have to be global and you need a touchmove step to get the position in touchend.. hope this is also what you needed..